# How to change the 'echo' position in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

1.I have created a login form and want to display username already in use please select another name. Want to change the position of echo in php. I have written echo in php code but i want to display that echo in html. How to display that?

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["sign_up"])) {
        $fname = $_POST["first_name"];
        $lname = $_POST["last_name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $user = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"]; 
        $login_id = $row["login_id"];
        $sql_email = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE email='$email'"; 
        $email_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_email); 
        $email_num = mysqli_num_rows($email_result);
        if ($email_num != 0) { //If there is already such username... // 
            $email_echo = '<span style="color:#e60000;text-align:center;">"There is user with that email.</span>'; // ...kill the script!
            $email_echo = 'There is user with that email.'; 
        } else { //conti 
            $sql_signUp = "INSERT INTO login(first_name, last_name, email, username, password ) 
            values('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$user', '$password')"; mysqli_query($conn, $sql_signUp); 
        } 

        $sql_username = "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='$user'"; //looking through existing usernames 
        $username_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_username); 
        $username_num = mysqli_num_rows($username_result);

        if ($username_num != 0) { //If there is already such username... 
            $username_echo = '<span style="color:#e60000;text-align:center;">"There is user with that username.</span>'; // ...kill the script! 
        } else { //conti 
            $sql_signUp = "INSERT INTO login(first_name, last_name, email, username, password ) values('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$user', '$password')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_signUp); 
        } 
    }

?>
    <div id="signup">
       <h1>Sign Up</h1>
       <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
          <div class="top-row">
             <div class="field-wrap"> <label> First Name<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text" required autocomplete="on" name="first_name"/> </div>
             <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Last Name<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text"required autocomplete="on" name="last_name"/> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Email Address<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="email"required autocomplete="on" name="email"/> <?php echo $email_echo //display some PHP here?> </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Username<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text" required autocomplete="on" name="username"/> </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Set A Password<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name="password"/> </div>
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" value="sign_up" name="sign_up"/>Register</button> 
       </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please format your code properly

Comment: Does not understand anything so, Could you please format your code properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check username_echo variable is set or not

```
<div id="signup">

       <h1>Sign Up</h1>
       <h4><?php if(isset($username_echo) && !empty($username_echo)) echo $username_echo;?></h4>
       <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
          <div class="top-row">
             <div class="field-wrap"> <label> First Name<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text" required autocomplete="on" name="first_name"/> </div>
             <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Last Name<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text"required autocomplete="on" name="last_name"/> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Email Address<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="email"required autocomplete="on" name="email"/> <?php echo $email_echo //display some PHP here?> </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Username<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="text" required autocomplete="on" name="username"/> </div>
          <div class="field-wrap"> <label> Set A Password<span class="req">*</span> </label> <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name="password"/> </div>
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" value="sign_up" name="sign_up"/>Register</button> 
       </form>
    </div>
```